# MS Planner - View my direct reports tasks

Tags: microsoft-planner

I am new to a company and want to be able to see the tasks that are already assigned to my new direct reports in MS Planner. We are members of 10+ plans and I don't want to have to go through each one.
Is there any way to see their tasks across all plans?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that functionality is available currently. There is however a [very popular User Voice item](https://planner.uservoice.com/forums/330525-microsoft-planner-feedback-forum/suggestions/15608670-view-all-tasks-assigned-to-a-single-person) related to your requirement.

One option could be to export the plans to Excel and then manipulate the data in Excel to achieve your requirement.

Another option would be to build your own solution using the [Planner REST API](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/planner-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0).